# Should a module implementing a filter delete the Drupal variables it uses, when uninstalled?

Tags: 6, hooks, input-formats

I checked some modules implementing an input filter, and (if not in few occasions) I have never seen the modules removing the  `module_name_$format` Drupal persistent variables when they are uninstalled.

Since a module should normally delete its Drupal persistent variables when it is uninstalled, is there a reason why an input filter module doesn't normally delete its own Drupal variables, for example because this is already done by Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module should be responsible for cleaning up after itself when it is uninstalled. There is no reason not to do this, unless some other modules depend on those variables but I very much doubt this is a case. If they depend on a module they probably depend on the entire module, not just some variables defined by it.

I, for example, use htmLawed and out of curiosity checked the `.install` file; it does clean the variables defined in the format "module_name_format_%".

As a best practice you should drop all the tables and delete the variables defined by your module, doing this by implementing `hook_uninstall` in your `.install` file.

- [Writing .install files (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/323314)